# Updates/transactions fail if write/validate rules are dependent on multiple parts of the update

Tags: firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

Updates and transactions will fail if one part of the update has a rule depending on another part of the update.

**User creation example**

**Rules**

```js
{ 
  "rules": {
      // Private user data
      "users": {
      "$uid": {
        ".read": "$uid === auth.uid",
        ".write": "$uid === auth.uid"
      }
    }
    // Public user data
    "profiles": {
      ".read": true,
      "$uid": {
        // The authed user can write only if they exist in /users.
        ".write": "$uid === auth.uid && root.child('users/' + $uid).exists()"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Update function**

```js
function createUser(uid, user, profile) {
  var updates = [];
  updates['/users/' + uid] = user;
  updates['/profiles/' + uid] = profile;

  // This will fail
  firebase.app().database().ref().update(updates, onComplete);
}

function onComplete(error) {
  if (error) console.log('error:', error);
  else console.log('success');
}
```

Comment: the rule checking logic must look at the uncommitted state of the db before the transaction; otherwise, the rules could be easily sidestepped, wouldn't you say?

Comment: Please share the minimal JSON that you're updating, the minimal security rules that you have and the write operation that fails.

Comment: @muratgu, That may be the case. It does seem like it would require a nontrivial amount of overhead to implement this on the server side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're checking against `root`, which refers to the data as it existed before the update.

To check against the new data, start from the `newData` variable. If you need to refer to data under the root, that means you need to use multiple `parent()` calls to get back to the top.

```
{ 
  "rules": {
    "profiles": {
      ".read": true,
      "$uid": {
        ".write": "$uid === auth.uid &&
                   newData.parent().parent().child('users/' + $uid).exists()"
      }
    },
    "users": {
      "$uid": {
        ".read": "$uid === auth.uid",
        ".write": "$uid === auth.uid"
      }
    }
  }
}
```